# Kibana filter: some unique values of a field are missing in the filter dropdown list

Tags: kibana

In the discover tab I want to filter by a particular value of a field. However, the value that I need doesn't appear in the "Values..." list even if I start typing it (so this is not connected with limit). If I type it manually and press Save, it works fine. Is it a bug or am I missing something?

[image]

Comment: Do you have logs containing that value for the field? Or is it an expected value?